# SQL Case When in Group By Rewrite in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have a SQL Server query and I rewrite this query in c# by using LINQ.

In the T-SQL query, there is `group by` with case when. How can I rewrite the query in C#?

```
  GROUP BY CAST(ISNULL(EnrollmentDate, CreatedDate) AS DATE),
                   (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN ISNULL(AccountId, 0) = 0
                            THEN [UserId]
                        ELSE AcoountId
                        END
                    )
```

I tried this;

```
  .GroupBy(t => new { (t.EnrollmentDate ?? t.CreatedDate).Date, })
```

But I can not rewrite the case when part in group by.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a preparation step.

You can wrap your object with a `Tuple` of `(string, T)`.

in `Item1` you will set the value you need for the key based on the logic:

```
CASE 
                        WHEN ISNULL(AccountId, 0) = 0
                            THEN [UserId]
                        ELSE AcoountId
                        END
```

And in second step you can create the group by you want.

Comment: So, how can I implement the new object in query.

Comment: Something like  `Item1 = AccountId ?? UserId`